# Trying to put an iframe and a div next to each while being responsive

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've written some code to try and put a google map iframe left of a div with some text and a button in it, inside of a footer, while trying to make the map and text responsive.

I'm having real trouble with it. Can anyone suggest anything, please?

Here is my HTML code:

```css
.map iframe {
  align: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 75%;
}

.map .openning {
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="ftr center">
  <div class="map left">
    <iframe src="URL HERE" style="border:none;"></iframe>
    <div class="openning">
      <h3>Opening Times</h3>
      <div id="days">
        <h4>Mon-Fri:</h4>
        <h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5>
        <h4>Sat-Sun:</h4>
        <h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5>
      </div>
      <button id="donate" class="btn pink small">Donate now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget all the right, float and text-align, you're mixing different features which have nothing to do with each other. Instead, I recommend to use flexbox, which makes everything really simple. Set the parent to display: flex and make the children 50% wide.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex > * {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <iframe src="https://example.com" style="border:none;"></iframe>
  
  <div class="right">
    <h3>Opening Times</h3>
    <div id="days">
      <h4>Mon-Fri:</h4><h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5><h4>Sat-Sun:</h4><h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5>
    </div>
    <button id="donate" class="btn pink small">Donate now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using percentage width and flex properties in css for responsiveness.

```
<body>
<div id="box">
    <h4>Mon-Fri:</h4>
    <h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5>
    <h4>Sat-Sun:</h4>
    <h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5>
  </div>
<div id="iframeWrapper">
  <iframe id="iframe">
</div>
</body>




body{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#iframeWrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
 }

#box{
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`align` is html property, not css. Try this:

```css
.map {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.map iframe {
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 70%;
}

.map .openning {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 28%;
    padding: 0 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ftr center">
        <div class="map left">
            <iframe src="URL HERE" style="border:none;"></iframe>
            <div class="openning">
            <h3>Opening Times</h3>
            <div id="days">
            <h4>Mon-Fri:</h4><h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5><h4>Sat-Sun:</h4><h5>00:00 - 00:00</h5>
            </div>
            <button id="donate" class="btn pink small">Donate now</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

More up-to-date solution would be to use flexbox